# helper.setText, Is it possible to send array more than in one row ( string) ? if yes , how

Tags: java, spring

I tried to make thus

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);

for (int a= 0; a<=i; a++){
        System.out.println("nameArrays.get(a) -"+nameArrays.get(a));
            helper.setText("Plain message", "<html><body><h2>"+nameArrays.get(a)+"</h2></body></html>" );
    }
```

In console I see:

```
nameArrays.get(a) -NameOne - 1pieces.
nameArrays.get(a) -GlenDeveron - 3pieces.
nameArrays.get(a) -Tomintoul - 5pieces.
```

But when I recieve email I see only last text - `Tomintoul - 5pieces.`
I have already studied the Forum and Help for 2 days and did not find the answer on my question

Comment: Use a stringbuilder to build the  the text and if the text ir ready you can set it using helper.setText();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code you override the message in every Loop. Use StringBuffer to build the string:

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("<html><body>");
for (int a= 0; a<=i; a++){
        System.out.println("nameArrays.get(a) -"+nameArrays.get(a));
        sb.append("<h2>"+nameArrays.get(a)+"</h2>");
    }

sb.append("</body></html>");
```

And after you have build the string you can set it to the helper:

```
        helper.setText("Plain message", sb.toString() );
```

Comment: Is it possible add image in this code? Now I send so: `FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File(imagePath+photo));`
`helper.addAttachment("ThankYou.jpg", file);`

Comment: @Viking yes it is. See here: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0504.html or this: http://jdpgrailsdev.github.io/blog/2014/12/09/email_inline_image_attachments.html

Comment: It's no go. I try, but photo and text can't  be in table together. I receive separate photo, and separate text. I want doing as table: first Photo, then namePhoto, then QuantityPhoto, then maybe price or another text, it's not buisness project.I try to understand as online stores work